# Recursive replace in a GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt

Say I have the following GADT AST:

```
data O a b c where 
    Add ::  O a a a
    Eq :: O a b Bool
    --... more operations

data Tree a where 
    N :: (O a b c) -> Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree c
    L :: a -> Tree a
```

Now I want to construct a function that replaces all `L`(eave)s of type `a` in the Tree, something like this:

```
f :: a -> Tree b -> Tree b
f x (L a) | typeof x == typeof a = L x
f x (L a) = L a
f x (N o a b) = N o (f x a) (f x b)
```

Would it be possible to construct such a function? (using classes maybe?)
Could it be done if changes are made to the GADTs?

I already have a typeof function: `typeof :: a -> Type` within a class.

Comment: If you want to compare types dynamically, that's usually an indication that your data structure design is not appropriate for the task at hand.  Can you explain what `f` is used for?

Comment: `f` is used to change one variable (leaf) into another. See it as performing lambda substitutions: Say I have the AST of `(a+1)`, then I want to replace `a` with the correct value so I can evaluate the value of the expression. One of my questions was how to design an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use type witnesses: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_witness

```
data O a b c where 
    Add ::  O a a a
    Eq :: O a b Bool

instance Show (O a b c) where
    show Add = "Add"
    show Eq = "Eq"

data Tree a where 
    T :: (Typeable a, Typeable b, Typeable c) => (O a b c) -> Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree c
    L :: a -> Tree a

instance (Show a) => Show (Tree a) where
    show (T o a b) = "(" ++ (show o) ++ " " ++ (show a) ++ " " ++ (show b) ++ ")"
    show (L a) = (show a)

class (Show a) => Typeable a where
    witness :: a -> Witness a

instance Typeable Int where
    witness _ = IntWitness

instance Typeable Bool where
    witness _ = BoolWitness

data Witness a where
    IntWitness :: Witness Int
    BoolWitness :: Witness Bool

dynamicCast :: Witness a -> Witness b -> a -> Maybe b
dynamicCast IntWitness  IntWitness a  = Just a
dynamicCast BoolWitness BoolWitness a = Just a
dynamicCast _ _ _ = Nothing

replace :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> b
replace a b = case dynamicCast (witness a) (witness b) a of
    Just v  -> v
    Nothing -> b

f :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => b -> Tree a -> Tree a
f x (L a) = L $ replace x a
f x (T o a b) = T o (f x a) (f x b)
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think this is possible with the current GADT unless you are okay with having a partially defined function. You can write

```
--f :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Tree b -> Tree a
f x (L a)
   | show (typeOf x) == show (typeOf a) = L x
```

but you can't make this function total because you would need

```
   | otherwise = L a
```

and that wont typecheck, since you just proved `L a :: Tree a` and `L x :: Tree x` are different types.

However, if you define the `GADT` as existentially quantified

```
data Tree where
    N :: (O a b c) -> Tree -> Tree -> Tree
    L :: Typeable a => a -> Tree

f :: Typeable a => a -> Tree -> Tree
f x (L a)
    | show (typeOf x) == show (typeOf a) = L x
    | otherwise = L a
```

you lose the type information in your `Tree`, but this typechecks and is total

another version that retains type information

```
data Tree a b c where
    N :: (O a b c) -> Tree a b c -> Tree a b c -> Tree a b c
    L :: Typeable a => a -> Tree a b c

f :: Typeable a => a -> Tree a b c -> Tree a b c
f x (L a)
    | show (typeOf x) == show (typeOf a) = L x
    | otherwise = L a
```

here you keep the type information for any possible value stored in a `L` in the `Tree` type. This might work if you only need a few different types, but would get bulky quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have some stuff to take care of the condition, but as you say it will not typecheck (I updated the question)

Comment: Great, a solution that works. Can I instead use some boxing type to maybe do something like this?: `f :: (Typeable a) => Box -> Tree a -> Tree a` and `data Box where B :: Typeable a => a -> B`. I'll try that.

Comment: The issue is that the type of your `Tree` `GADT` cant depend on the type of the values at its leaves. You want to have a `Tree` with some leaves containing a value of one type, and some leaves with a value of a completely different type and the type of the `Tree` cant be both. See my edited answer for a possible solution if you need the type information.

Comment: That is not the problem. And your last version of `f` cannot recurse on N (cannot determine a ~ b). I did solve it using some code trickery anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. Are you sure that `f` cannot recurse on `N`? I have no problem writing `f x (N o a b) = N o (f x a) (f x b)` with my definition of f.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it can (I mixed up the order of the types), but it cannot construct a general AST correctly (N Eq a b would for example be wrong). The proper type of N should be `N :: (O a b c) -> Tree a1 b1 a -> Tree a2 b2 b -> Tree a b c`, and then we are back to square one.